# Why Tkinter window opens so slowly?

Tags: python, tkinter, api-design

I coded a program which converts cryptocurrencies, with a basic user interface(will work on it later). My code works but for some reason the tkinter window opens so slowly. Does it have something to do with me having too much API requests on my code, or is it something else? How can I get the program running faster?

Here's the code:

```
def GUIinterfaceConversion():
    # Retrieve the api data
    apiURL = "https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=my_key"
    rawData = requests.get(apiURL)
    data = json.loads(rawData.text)

    # Get the Currency Abbreviations & Full Names
    currencyOutputs = []
    for element in data:
        currencyOutput = {"Name":element["name"],"Abbreviation":element["currency"]}
        currencyOutputs.append(currencyOutput)

    # Window Layout
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Cryptocurrency Converter")
    window.geometry("1300x1000")

    # Listbox Layout
    Lb1 = tk.Listbox(window, width=40, height=20)
    Lb2 = tk.Listbox(window, width=40, height=20)
    for output in currencyOutputs:
        Lb1.insert(0, output["Name"] + "(" + output["Abbreviation"] + ")")
        Lb2.insert(0, output["Name"] + "(" + output["Abbreviation"] + ")")

    Lb1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3, anchor="center")
    Lb2.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3, anchor="center")

    # On Selection
    Label1 = tk.Label(window, text="")
    Label1.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.55,anchor="center")
    Label2 = tk.Label(window, text="")
    Label2.place(relx=0.7,rely=0.55,anchor="center")
    def labelChange(event, label, listbox):
        label['text'] = "Converting From: " + listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    
    Lb1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda _: labelChange(event=any,label=Label1,listbox=Lb1))
    Lb2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda _: labelChange(event=any,label=Label2,listbox=Lb2))

    # Conversion Label
    LabelConverted = tk.Label(window)
    LabelConverted.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.65,anchor="center")

    # Conversion Button
    def convert():
        firstElement = Label1['text'].split(': ')[1].split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
        secondElement = Label2['text'].split(': ')[1].split("(")[1].split(")")[0]

        # Get API
        convertingApi = f"https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=my_key={firstElement}"
        convertedApi = f"https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=my_key&ids={secondElement}"
        converting = json.loads(requests.get(convertingApi).text)
        converted = json.loads(requests.get(convertedApi).text)

        # Generate the ratio and the final amount
        twoCurrenciesRatio = float(converting[0]['price'])/float(converted[0]['price'])
        finalAmount = format(twoCurrenciesRatio,'.8f')
        LabelConverted['text'] = finalAmount

    B = tk.Button(window, text="Convert", command=convert)
    B.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.55,anchor="center")

    window.mainloop()

GUIinterfaceConversion()
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I think that `requests.get(apiURL)` is slowing down your code is that if what you mean

Comment: Yes, but it is needed. Is there a way that I can have the same functionality but not having to deal with API's this much?(Thx a lot for the response btw)

Comment: You can split the `requests` call in another thread and use python variables (not tkinter widget) to update the display. The problem is that the code can become very difficult to maintain. Have you used threading before?

Comment: Seems like a prime example to try out async.

Comment: I haven't tried multithreading before. You're right, maybe that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, for some reason it works way faster today. I'll let you know if I have any other problems to deal with.